# Creating REST API with custom type

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, h2

Hello I am trying to create a rest API for a homework and they are asking me to create two endpoints the firsts one:

> POST /client
>
> {"money": 1000}

Response:

> {"id": 1,"money": 1000,"orders": []}

The second one:

> POST /client/:id/order
>
> {"date": 17/09/2005,"type": "Pick up","dish": "tacos","total_items":
> 5,"item_price": 2}

Response

> {"client_info": {"money": 990,"orders": [      {"dish":
> "tacos","total_items": 5,"item_price": 2}
> ]  },"order_errors": []}

For this purpose I created the following files:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "CLIENTS")
public class Client{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private ArrayList<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();
    private Float cash;
     
    //I have getters and setters
}
```

And

```
@RestController
public class ClientController {
    @Autowired
    private ClientRepository restRepository;

@GetMapping("/client")
public List<Client> getAllOrders() {
    return restRepository.findAll();
}


@PostMapping("/client")
public Client createAccount(@RequestBody Client client) {
    return restRepository.save(client);
}

@PutMapping("/client/{id}/order")
public ResponseEntity<Client> updateOrders(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long clientId, @Validated @RequestBody Issuer orderDetails)  throws ResourceNotFoundException {
    Client client= restRepository
            .findById(clientId)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Usuario no encontrado: " + userId));
    client.getOrders().add(orderDetails);
    client.setMoney(client.getCash() - (orderDetails.getTotal_items() * orderDetails.getItem_price()));

    final Account updatedClient = restRepository.save(client);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(updatedClient );
}
```

}

The problem that I'm having is that when I add an order to a client I get the following error:

> "could not serialize; nested exception is
> org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not serialize"

I suppose it is because I have a custom type "Order" but I don't know how to solve it. I am using an h2 memory database.

Also I would like to know if my approach to have the second endpoint in the same controller is correct

Comment: Post _the entire error message_. Also, this is a case where you _must_ use the `List` interface instead of `ArrayList` for your `orders` so that Hibernate can insert its own managed `List` implementation. (Note as well that you should almost never use `Float` for any reason, and you definitely should not use floating-point types for money; use `BigDecimal` instead.)

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'profileController' defined in URL  Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repositoryRestConfiguration' defined in class path resource Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext'

Comment: Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.example.task.Order, at table: users, for columns:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define relationship between `Client` and `Order` by JPA annotation, such as:

```java
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "CLIENTS")
public class Client {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "client")
    private List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();

    // ...
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "ORDERS")
public class Order {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Client client;

    // ...
}
```